# What happens to washing machine with bad bearings?

Tags: appliances, washing-machine

A relative is having problems with an older maytag top load washing machine. During the spin cycle the machine makes a loud noise.

The noise starts to get loud once the water has emptied. It just sounds like the regular noise just louder. Almost like a large high power fan. No grinding our shaking.

I think it might be bad bearings, pulley or belt. But open to other suggestions.

What I'm curious about is if it is the bearings... What happens if the washer is continued to be used in this condition and any idea how long it might lady until the bearings completely fall and become unusable?

Answer (score 2):

If it is the bearings, on some washers that is can be an expensive repair (on my washer I was quoted $600) which often means it isn't a DIY fix.

If you don't repair it, the sound will get louder and louder and could eventually damage the drum and shaft. As more bearings break down or fall out the washer will just stop working.

Comment: Was this a commercial or industrial washing machine?

Comment: @wallyk this was my home washing machine. Still running, just very loud during the spin cycle.

Answer (score 2):

Did you check to make sure the washer is sitting evenly on the floor? If not, it will bounce around and make a ton of noise -- and shorten its life. It's easy to fix that, by screwing or unscrewing the feet while the machine is off.

The issue you describe ranges from cheap and easy to very expensive to replace. If it is a belt, you can probably pick one up for $30 and do it yourself. If you're looking at bearings, to Mark's point, you'd do yourself a disservice by not just replacing the machine. If you continue to use a machine with bad bearings, obviously the machine will eventually fail, but at what cost? There may be a potential for a motor to overheat and cause fire (assuming it isn't thermally protected, or the breaker doesn't catch it first).

Answer (score 1):

I had a noisy machine and I did bet on a bearing. I ignored it for a while and eventually I found a little metal hairclip between the outer and the inner drum making the noise. Thought I let u know.

Good Luck